# Função para incrementar valor dentro da div

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer uma função para incrementar (a cada 20ms) +1 dentro `<div>`, de acordo com o valor que vai estar dentro dela:

Por exemplo:

```
<li class="marcacao" onMouseOver="aumenta('html')">HTML5 e CSS3
<div id="html" class="nivel">100</div>
</li>

valorInicial = 0;
function aumenta(id){
    setInterval(function(){
    var elemento = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;//pega o valor da div (no caso numero)
    if(valorInicial <= elemento){
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = valorInicial++;
    }},20)
}
```

**Como podem ver a função não está funcionando, acho que o problema é no setInterval, como posso arrumar isso?**

Comment: respondido denovo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que está a usar o conteúdo do elemento para **dois** efeitos:

1. Guardar o valor atual (`valorInicial`).
2. Guardar o valor final pretendido.

Quando chega à linha de mudar o innerHTML, ele acaba por alterar o valor final por arrasto.

Vamos então começar por tentar fazer o contador incrementar, sem esperar que ele pare eventualmente.

HTML:

```
<li class="marcacao" onMouseOver="aumenta('html')">HTML5 e CSS3
<div id="html" class="nivel">100</div>
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
function aumenta(id){
    var valorAtual = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        var elemento = document.getElementById(id);//pega a div com o número
        elemento.innerHTML = valorAtual++;
    },20)
}
```

Vamos pôr agora um limite fixo:

```
function aumenta(id){
    var valorAtual = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        var elemento = document.getElementById(id);//pega a div com o número
        var valor = elemento.innerHTML;
        if (valorAtual <= 100) {
            elemento.innerHTML = valorAtual++;
        }
    },20)
}
```

Por fim, vamos usar o valor dentro do elemento para decidir até onde ir:

```
function aumenta(id){
    var elemento = document.getElementById(id);//pega a div com o número 
    var valorAtual = 0;
    var valorFinal = elemento.innerHTML;

    setInterval(function(){
        if (valorAtual <= valorFinal) {
            elemento.innerHTML = valorAtual++;
        }
    },20)
}
```

Importante ter em conta que isto tem dois problemas:

1. O setInterval não para de ser chamado, simplesmente passa a não fazer nada. (mas continua a torrar energia)
2. Não funciona bem se o utilizador retirar o rato de cima do elemento e voltar a passar em cima.

Uma correção para o 1 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Hxf5/2/)):

```
function aumenta(id){
    var elemento = document.getElementById(id);//pega a div com o número
    var valorAtual = 0;
    var valorFinal = elemento.innerHTML;

    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if (valorAtual <= valorFinal) {
            elemento.innerHTML = valorAtual++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    },20)
}
```

Também há formas de resolver o segundo problema, mas depende de como quiser que a função se comporte.

Comment: Muito obrigado @luiscubal, compreendi perfeitamente

Answer (score 1):

Não tem nada errado. O teu código funciona.

Pode conferir no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aTq4/)

**Respondedo a pergunta após editada**

Tem alguns errors de sintaxe e de lógica. Acho que tu quer [isso](http://jsfiddle.net/5aTq4/1/).

Aconselho a parar a pensar um pouco antes de postar a pergunta denovo :-)

E possívelmente usar um plugin de barra de progresso ao invés de codar na mão.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta @fotanus. Na verdade eu quero incrementar um valor dentro da div.

Comment: @Odair O quê? Continua pouco claro o que é pretendido.

Comment: @luiscubal o que eu quero é pegar o valor que está dentro da div (100 por exemplo) e iniciar uma contagem que vá de 0 a 100, como uma espécie de contador

Comment: @Odair Ok. Acho que já percebi.

Comment: Muito obrigado @fotanus e me desculpa por editar a pergunta.

Comment: @Fotanus, no caso, você fez essa comparação se o valor inicial for menor que 100, só que eu preciso que o valor inicial seja algo como: se valor ,+ valor_que_esta_dentr_da_div

Comment: @Odair o problema é que dae tu tá mudando o valor da div na primeira vez que executa. Um segundinho, deixa eu editar isso...

Comment: @Odair: Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/5aTq4/3/)

Comment: @fotanus, valeu mesmo cara, desculpa o trabalho rs

Comment: @Odair estamos aí pra isso :-)

Answer (score 1):

Re-organizei o seu código. O valor inicial deve estar fora do `setInterval` para não ser re-escrito.

Teste assim:

```
var valorInicial = 0;

function aumenta(id) {
    var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
    var valorElemento = elemento.innerHTML;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (valorInicial <= valorElemento) {
            elemento.innerHTML = valorInicial;
        }
        valorInicial++;
    }, 20)
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/QT686/)

Comment: Tenha só cuidado com a forma como parseInt funciona em strings que comecem em '0' (octal), como '010' (que dá 8 em vez de 10)

Comment: Perfeito @Sergio, muito obrigado e desculpa ter editado a pergunta.

Comment: @luiscubal, verdade, obrigado. Tirei, neste caso nem precisa...

Comment: @Odair, não tem problema. Ainda bem que encontrou solução!